# org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error from GET

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, microservices

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException:
> Type definition error: [simple type, class
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$RepositoryAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource];
> nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
> serializer found for class
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$RepositoryAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource
> and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid
> exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through
> reference chain:
> java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98["advisors"]->org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor[3]->org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor["advice"]->org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor["transactionAttributeSource"])]
> with root cause

---

**order_service _microservice ERROR:**

: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$**InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error from GET http://localhost:9091/api/inventory/?skucode=order_10&skucode=order_20&skucode=order_30]** with root cause

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error from GET http://localhost:9091/api/inventory/?skucode=order_10&skucode=order_20&skucode=order_30
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:239) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ⇢ 500 from GET http://localhost:9091/api/inventory/?skucode=order_10&skucode=order_20&skucode=order_30 [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientRespons

**INVENTORY_microservice:**

**controller class:**

```
package com.Inventory_microservice.Inventory_microservice.Controller;

import com.Inventory_microservice.Inventory_microservice.Repository.InventoryRepository;
import com.Inventory_microservice.Inventory_microservice.Service.InventoryService;
import com.Inventory_microservice.Inventory_microservice.model.Inventory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/inventory")
public class InventoryController {

    @Autowired
    private InventoryService inventoryService;
    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<InventoryRepository> isInStock(@RequestParam List<String> skucode ) {
        return inventoryService.isInStock(skucode);

    }
}
```

**service class:**

```
package com.Inventory_microservice.Inventory_microservice.Service;

import com.Inventory_microservice.Inventory_microservice.Repository.InventoryRepository;
import com.Inventory_microservice.Inventory_microservice.dto.InventoryResponse;
import com.Inventory_microservice.Inventory_microservice.model.Inventory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class InventoryService {

    @Autowired
    private InventoryRepository inventoryRepository;

    @Transactional
    public List<InventoryRepository> isInStock(List<String> Skucode)
    {

        return inventoryRepository.findBySkucodeIn(Skucode).stream().map(inventory -> checkstock(inventory)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private InventoryRepository checkstock(Inventory inventory) {
        InventoryResponse inventoryResponse=new InventoryResponse();
        inventoryResponse.setSkucode(inventory.getSkucode());
        inventoryResponse.setInstock(inventory.getQuantity()>0);
        return inventoryRepository;
    }

}
```

**ORDER_MICROSERVICE:**

**Controller class**
package com.OrderService.order_service_microsevice.Controller;

```
import com.OrderService.order_service_microsevice.Service.OrderService;
import com.OrderService.order_service_microsevice.dto.RequestOrder;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/order")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public String createOrder(@RequestBody @NotNull RequestOrder requestOrder){


        System.out.println("calling Order controller class");
        orderService.placeOrder(requestOrder);
        return  "Order placed Successfully";
    }

}
```

Service class:

```
package com.OrderService.order_service_microsevice.Service;

import com.OrderService.order_service_microsevice.Repository.OrderRepository;
import com.OrderService.order_service_microsevice.dto.InventoryResponse;
import com.OrderService.order_service_microsevice.dto.OrderListItemsDto;
import com.OrderService.order_service_microsevice.dto.RequestOrder;
import com.OrderService.order_service_microsevice.model.Order;
import com.OrderService.order_service_microsevice.model.OrderItemList;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
@Transactional
public class OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    public void placeOrder(@NotNull RequestOrder requestOrder) {

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setOrderNumber(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        List<OrderItemList> orderItemLists =requestOrder.getOrderListItemsDtos()
                .stream()
                .map(this::maptodto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        order.setOrderItemList(orderItemLists);

        List<String> skucodes=order.getOrderItemList()
                .stream()
                .map(orderItemList -> orderItemList.getSkucode())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());


        //here we need to call inventory microservice to get the response
        InventoryResponse[] inventoryResponsesArray=webClient.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:9091/api/inventory/",
                        uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("skucode",skucodes)
                                .build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(InventoryResponse[].class)
                .block();

        boolean allproductsinstock= Arrays.stream(inventoryResponsesArray).allMatch(InventoryResponse::isInstock);

        if(allproductsinstock){
            orderRepository.save(order);
        }
        else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product is not available in stock");
        }

    }

    private @NotNull OrderItemList maptodto(@NotNull OrderListItemsDto orderListItemsDto) {
        OrderItemList orderItemList = new OrderItemList();
        orderItemList.setSkucode(orderListItemsDto.getSkucode());
        orderItemList.setQuantity(orderListItemsDto.getQuantity());
        orderItemList.setPrice(orderListItemsDto.getPrice());

        return orderItemList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jagan Reddy
I think the issue seems to be here where we are setting the url - 
InventoryResponse[] inventoryResponseArray = webClientBuilder.build().get()
                .uri("http:/inventory-service/api/inventory",

Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: Lmao! I am getting the same error cuz I am following the same tutorial by Programming Techie. (>_<)

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be in your @GetMapping and @PostMapping

You are trying to return a list of InventoryRepository which is not possible you should be returning a List of Entities instead.

```
@Autowired
    private InventoryService inventoryService;
    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<InventoryRepository> isInStock(@RequestParam List<String> skucode ) {
        return inventoryService.isInStock(skucode);

    }
```

Instead you should be doing :

```
 @Autowired
    private InventoryService inventoryService;
    @GetMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<Inventory> isInStock(@RequestParam List<String> skucode ) {
        return inventoryService.isInStock(skucode);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

InventoryController is cause for this issue, due to compiler :

Compiler is not able to store method parameter names while generating the class files. you can enable this compiler option in eclipse IDE/STS. Go to-

Project properties -> Java compiler -> enable/check "Project specific settings" -> enable/check "Store information about method parameters(usable via reflection)"

Hope this helps.