# Why is my microservice not registering both instances with the Eureka server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices, netflix-eureka

I have set up two instances of my microservice on different ports, but only one instance is visible on the Eureka dashboard. I have set the following properties in my microservice's `application.properties` file:

```
server.port=0
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
spring.application.name=Inventory-Service
```

However, when I check the Eureka dashboard, I can only see one instance of my microservice. I am sure that both instances are running. What could be the issue?

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Cloud. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/843). The problem is that the default instance ID that is used to register with Eureka looks like this:

```
${spring.application.name}:${server.port}
```

So even if you run your microservice on a random port by using `server.port=0`, the ID it uses within Eureka in both cases is `Inventory-Service:0`. Since the ID has to be unique, only one instance is registered in Eureka.

[image: Example of Eureka dashboard containing a single instance with ID Inventory-Service:0]

The solution to this problem is to either not work with random ports, or to make sure you generate a unique Eureka ID for each instance.

For example:

```
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${random.int}
```

[image: Example of Eureka dashboard containing two instances, each with a unique random ID]

Comment: thanks it worked.But I had to keep the server port line and eureka.instance.instance-id line to make it work.

Comment: could you please answer this question I am facing a problem here also 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73985345/org-springframework-web-reactive-function-client-webclientresponseexceptioninte